# Best GUI Toolkit/Framework for Java and Python

Tags: java, python, swing, user-interface, toolkit

I've been write window programs with C# + WPF for a while now. It is very good, has alot of rich elements as of .NET 4.5 but I dont really buy the idea of porting window based programs to other operating system like OS X using mono and others.

I started working on Java and Python, I haven't written any desktop based program with anyone of them yet as there are war of GUI framework/toolkit out there and everyone is just getting religious about things.

I need some clarification hence the following Questions, mind you these questions might be answered before but like I said, Clarifications:

- What is the different between GUI toolkit and GUI framework
- For Java programming, I see swing is integrated with Netbeans, from my research, people are speaking of qt's Jambi and GTK for java and python, I have no idea about any of these and I want to know, (1) Which do you use and why? (for Java and python), (2) Visual studio do all the magic for WPF and C#, which IDE can do these magic in java and python.
- Lastly, I want you all to know that my asking these question is just to know which rich, powerful GUI and cross platform toolkit/framework (Whichever the right term is) is best for java and python with easy learning curve.

Constructive criticism  are welcome BUT, I will be glad if there are answers.

Comment: There's nothing in java (or elsewhere) like WPF.

Comment: Swing is integrated in Java, not NetBeans, it's OS independent so anything you write on Swing, may look the same on all platforms or you can make it look like any other native application, it's alternative is AWT, which is a bit more platform specific, but it's worth the shot.

Comment: I love Python, but I think for windows applications WPF and Visual Studio are far superior to anything else I've tried. In Python, GUI toolkits I know of are Tkinter, which comes with the standard library, and wxpython.

Comment: Thanks all, I guess folks around here could be harsh sometimes for putting this post as off-topic. believe me many people are asking this question. I believe people in the java & python world always create some wheel for themselves. I guess that is the way out. I will see what I can try for myself. All I want is a cross-platform programming language with a powerful GUI support. I guess we are still in the stone age as there is nothing of such

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[JavaFX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) seems like a poor imitation of WPF.

Still, I have not seen any examples of how much (if at all) support does JavaFX provide for MVVM, which is what makes WPF the best UI Framework in the history of mankind.

from what I've seen, swing is more similar to winforms than anything else, if you come from WPF that will feel like going back to the stone age.

*Side Note:* java IDEs don't hold a candle compared to Visual Studio.

Comment: That is the issue with me, going back to the stone age. will see what I can do though.

Comment: @temitayo If you don't want to go back to the stone age, then don't use java at all. it's at least 10 years behind C#. get Xamarin and you can create cross platform applications in C#.

Comment: My question is, how reliable and bug free is it? Besides, soon I will be working on a server (pure UNIX based application) and a unix enable programming language is imminent.

Comment: +1 for this. After going through Xamarin, well it looks good to me BUT, like I said earlier, how much should I trust it. at least for business applications this time.

Comment: @Temitayo I think you're mistaking some concepts here. UNIX is a server OS, and no one in their sane mind will EVER use that for a simple client/workstation / personal PC. Regardless of what you use for a SERVER, your CLIENT can still be (and you will probably have more chances of succeeding) implemented for: Windows, Android and Mac.

Comment: For Windows, there's NOTHING like WPF. for Android and MAC, use Xamarin. JavaFX seems to immature from what I've seen, and swing and others are just dinosaurs.

Comment: Dinosaurs they really are but actually, what I mean is, we are looking forward to creating application that wont run on windows, will run mostly on Linux boys like Ubuntu and the likes, I know I am really mixing something up but window isn't involved.... Xaramin will be very good for Business/Agile Applications. Will give it a try.

Comment: @HighCore - Nothing can come close to the quality of IntelliJ http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/21987/how-is-intellij-better-than-eclipse. Having said that, Eclipse is pretty much as good as Visual Studio.

Comment: @jwill my point still stands. java is desperately waiting for a 2014 release to have "something" that tries to imitate LINQ, a feature that was released in C# in 2007. The same with javafx being a horrendously poor imitation of WPF. No IDE can compensate those lackings, no matter how good it might be.

Comment: @jwill I prefer a million times to have Microsoft working on improving the language and framework (async/await was introduced in C# 5), than having a better IDE while still having to deal with the limitations of a crappy language that doesn't even have properties, like java.

Answer (score 0):

I know QT is for Java (and Python of course). It is well documented and is used by a lot of people around the world.

Comment: I edited your post so that it is clearer.

Comment: Thanks @iCodez, swing looks more like window form to me and from my WPF experience, it just like doing things the old way. I dont really like it. but milssky, I might give gt jambi and pyQt a trial like you said. Thanks again.